# Should I use a single framework codebase for multiple sites or one for each site?

Tags: oop, frameworks, coldfusion, installation, dry

Here's the situation:

- Multiple sites are built using a certain framework.
- All sites are hosted on the same server.
- Each site has its own database

Since all the sites are hosted on the same location and they all have the framework code in common, I could easely install the framework once on the server and have each site use the same files as their framework code. 
This way I only have 1 framework installation that is used by all the websites.

The second option is to have each site work with its own installation of the framework.

pro's and con's of option 1:

- Only have to maintain 1 codebase for the framework of multiple websites
- Framework updates instantly apply for all the websites
- Should 1 site have different needs of the framework or have code that's no longer compatible with the latest framework version, custom framework compatibility patches become required. (there is not always time or budget to keep legacy projects compatible with the latest framework version)

pro's and con's of option 2:

- Seperate framework for each site to maintain
- Framework updates have to be applied seperately for each site
- Should 1 site have different needs of the framework or has no budget to be maid compatible with the latest framework update, we simply don't update that site's framework installation.
- If it's really necessary, a site could quickly modify its framework to match the needs without interfering with other sites on the server.

So option 1 seems easier to maintain, while option 2 is much more flexible. I don't know what's most important.
Which of the 2 options is the overall the best choice? Or are there more options possible?

Comment: Option 2, always. Always reduce your global state to a minimum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I approach this slightly differently.

I'd have a dir structure like this:

```
/sites/
    /site1/
    /site2/
    [etc]
/framework/
    /1.0/
    /1.1/
    /1.x/
    [etc]
```

Then within each site have a /framework mapping which points to the version of the framework that site is using.  That way each site's framework version is independent of the others: if one site needs a different framework version than the others (stuck on an old version, needs a new version before the other sites have been tested with it), then you have control over that sort of granularity.  Equally, changing the codebase in `/framwork/nightly/` (for example) will "automatically" update all sites with their /framework mapping pointing to that bleeding-edge version of the codebase.

Comment: I agree with this solution. Build a 'platform'. Beyond frameworks there are often times internal services can be leveraged on multiple sites.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I will always have each site using its own framework codebase, or at least using a shared codebase frozen at a set version.  The problem with sharing the framework is that with each update, you'd have to test each site using that shared codebase to ensure they are still working as expected.  What also happens when the framework deprecates a feature you use in one of your sites? It could prevent you from updating, leaving you open to security issues.

Option 2 does give you more of a maintenance overhead but it's the safest approach in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a couple factors.

How many developers working on the sites? Is the framework well supported, documented?  Is there a *better framework available (better by documentation, overhead (memory footprint) and community support).  Which choice would look better 12 months or longer down the road.

Choice 1 is appealing for its consistency and familiarity.

Choice 2 is appealing for its potential, learning and future growth.